# How to define a common location once in NGINX and share it across multiple server blocks?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, configuration

I have several server blocks, each one corresponds to a different domain. All of them share a common location that has the purpose of renewing SSH certificates (for those familiar with this, it's the *.well-known* route that Letsencrypt uses for that purpose, just in case someone out here already solved this ;) ).

I'd like to define this location once and share it across each different server block, but I can't seem to find an appropriate directive in the documentation. Any pointers are deeply appreciated :)

Comment: There are already tons of answers to this. Just define the location block outside of the server blocks.

Comment: Sorry for that, I searched for similar questions and read all suggested answers when writing this and none was about this. You can define a location block outside of a server block?

Comment: What about using `include`?

Comment: I would define a location block in an include file? By itself?